# Find all analytic functions in the disk $|z-2|<2$ such that $f \left(2+\frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{1-n}{5n+3} + \sin{\left(\frac{n \pi}{2} \right)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Find all analytic functions (or prove that no such exist) inside the disk $|z-2|<2$ that satisfy the following condition:

$$f \left(2+\frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{1-n}{5n+3} + \sin{\left(\frac{n \pi}{2} \right)}, \ n \in \mathbb{N}$$

For $n=2k$ the expression simplifies quite a bit since $\sin{\left(\frac{n \pi}{2} \right)}= \sin{\left(k \pi \right)} = 0$ so we're left with $$f \left(\frac{4k+1}{2k}\right) = \frac{1-2k}{10k+3}$$

Similarly for $n=4k-3$ and $n=4n-1$ we can simplify the sinus expression to $1$ and $-1$. So we're getting $3$ different expressions for $f\left(2+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ based on whether $n=2k$ , $n=4k-3$ or $n=4k-1$. My idea is to use the identity theorem for any of these two expressions and prove that no such function exists but I can't quite tie it all together.

Comment: How about just simply solving $2+1/n=z$ for $n$ and then plugging in. This function of $z$ must agree with the old one. Then see if it is analytic or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is correct, there is also a simpler one: assume that such a function exists. Then using continuity of $f$ we get

$$f(2) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f \left( 2+\frac{1}{n} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1-n}{5n+3} + \sin \frac{n \pi}{2} \right).$$

But the limit on the right clearly does not exist, which is a contradiction.

Comment: My answer is correct now (thanks to you), but yours is better, of course. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is a multiple of $4$, then\begin{align}f\left(2+\frac1n\right)&=\frac{1-n}{5n+3}\\&=\frac{1/n-1}{5+3/n}\\&=\frac{2+1/n-3}{-1+3(2+1/n)}.\end{align}Now, for each $z\in D_2(2)$, let $g(z)=\frac{z-3}{-1+3z}$. Then, by the identity theorem, $g=f$. But that's impossible, since $g(3)\ne f(3)$: $g(3)=0$, whereas$$f(3)=f\left(2+\frac11\right)=1.$$So, no such function $f$ exists.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Is $z$ equal to $\frac{1}{n}$ or $2+\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: $z$ is equal to $1/n$ here. So it is not true that $f(2+1/n)=...$ but $f(1/n)=...$ We therefore have to check that $g(z)=f(z-2)$ is analytic on $D_2(2)$ or that $f$ is analytic on $D_2(0)$ which it is clearly not.

Comment: @Adayah I'm glad you've asked that question. My answer was wrong.

Comment: @DreaDk Please see my revised answer.